# Is there a way to prevent apt from looking for i386 packages in multi-arch mode (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates, 64-bit

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent `apt` looking for an i386 version of a package for a particular repo/package?

For example, I recently got this error when doing `apt-get update`:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

I know Google has stopped support for the 32-bit version of Chrome, so it is pointless `apt` looking for any i386 versions of this packages.

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome-apt-error-ubuntu

Comment: @muru, you are right it is a duplicate. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.